Visualizing 10D
With 4D we can make a 1D array with 3D subplots to visualize time. With 10D I wonder if having 3D subplots that are 3D plus animation would be possible to utilize to visualize string theory, or is it just nonsense to discretize it in this way?

"To deal with hyper-planes in a 14-dimensional space, visualize a 3-D space and say “fourteen” to yourself very loudly. Everyone does it." - Geoffrey Hinton

We cannot visualize 4D. Here is the 2D projection of the 3D projection of a rotating 4D cube. It does not help me at all.

And if you think 4D is just 3D plus a time evolution, you are not in 4D proper, you are stuck to a specific foliation and it is very misleading to think you can grok anything that way.

Not really. I am just in a subset. Doesn't have to be a foliation. Could be xyt with z as animation dimension.

Animation allows us to visualise one additional dimension - essentially time in the animation adds one dimension to the underlying plot. So animating a 2D plot can help to visualise a 3D object; animating a 3D plot can help to visualise a 4D object. To visualise a 10D object you would have to animate a 9D plot.

Yes, I mean we can plot 9D by having a 3d array of 3d plots. I just don't know if the discretization makes sense in the case of string theory or if you need like a million subplots then. (For example in blender or similar software).

The number of subplots would grow quickly, indeed. At a certain point visualization starts to break down in favor of just really good understandings of the math…

Do you think the "intra voxel"-transition maps could look like teleportation to us, like a voxel/subplot at earth could be adjacent to a voxel in andromeda in the compactified dimensions represented by the voxel/subplot (if that is how you slice the cake) rather than adjacent to another voxel/subplot beside it here on earth as in the "inter voxel"-transition map? I am using it as a mental visualization guide so I am not limited by the RAM memory in Blender ;)
